# Listening to Model Changed By An Unrelated Component - Angular 7

Tags: angular, service, observable

I am trying to convert an existing app to Angular. I'm very new to Angular and really struggling with a lot of things I would expect to be dead simple. The latest is trying to capture model changes in an unrelated component.

My Structure: App > (Layout / Data Service) > (Component A / Component B)

Component A is subscribed to a data service whose model represents the values of a bunch of custom child components. These child components modify input and emit back a numeric value to Component A which in turn updates the model in the Data Service. No problem here this works as described.

Component B is also subscribed to the same data service and displays a result based on further calculations of the models values. The issue is when an input value is changed on Component A's children Component B's values are getting updated, but I am unable to trigger my UpdataCalculations() function when they are. To solve this I have added ngDoCheck() and placed my function in there, but this feels really gross to me. What I would really like to do is add an onChange listener to the model at the Component B level.

So I guess my question is A: Is this even possible with Angular? and B: Is there a better way to accomplish this?

Service:

```
export class JobDataService {
  private jobData = new BehaviorSubject(new Job_Info_View_Model);
  currentJob$ = this.jobData.asObservable();
  constructor() {}
}
```

Component B:

```
  constructor(
    private jobData: JobDataService,
  ) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.jobData.currentJob$.subscribe( (observing: Job_Info_View_Model) => { this.currentJob = observing; } );
  }

  ngDoCheck() {
    this.UpdataCalculations();
  }
```

Thank you for any help

EDIT: It really doesn't make sense for Component A & B to be a single component so I would like to avoid that if I can.

Answer (score 0):

`ngOnChanges` hook gets called when fields that are marked by `@Input()` decorators get new values from the parent component. `ngDoCheck` one gets called on every change detection, and that is very often. in your case subject is used and subscription callback is called every time the value updates, so the best option is to make calculations just in that callback.

```
this.jobData.currentJob$.subscribe( (observing: Job_Info_View_Model) => { 
  this.currentJob = observing;
  this.UpdataCalculations();
} );
```

Comment: So your solution is actually how I thought it should be done, but it seems that the subscribe callback function only gets executed on the initial ngOnInit().

Comment: it is executed every time when event comes. add method to your service like `public updateCurrentJob(job) {this.jobData.next(job);}` and all the subscribers will get it

Comment: I am a little unclear about where I would call this new method from as Angular is binding directly to and updating "job" and the issue is I can not trap the ngOnChange event from Component A or B due to the changes being made are in a Child element.

Comment: you are unable to capture your event in hook because there is no hook that gets called in your situation. just call `jobDataService.updateCurrentJob` in component A which will update the observable value and call your subscription callback